# Equivalent of dwAllocationGranularity in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, allocation, granularity

What is the equivalent of [`dwAllocationGranularity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958.aspx) in Linux? In Windows, it's defined as:

> The granularity for the starting address at which virtual memory can be allocated.

Note that this is *not* the same thing as `PAGE_SIZE`, which is the granularity of a *physical* page.
(On Windows, the virtual address granularity is 64 KiB on x86, whereas the page size is of course 4 KiB.)

Comment: Perhaps it does not have one; perhaps the granularity is always guaranteed to be PAGE_SIZE on Linux? Do you have a specific case where you would need a number such as this?

Comment: @flodin: Yeah I do have a specific case in front of me, but the code is not relevant here. If it doesn't have one then please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nearest equivalent of VirtualAlloc on Linux is mmap which, like VirtualAlloc, allows you to specify a desired allocation target address of the allocated memory. On Windows, this address must be aligned on the allocation granularity. On Linux, I quote from the mmap man page:

> If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as a hint about where to
>   place the mapping; on Linux, **the mapping will be created at a nearby
>   page boundary**.

As far as I know, there is no situation where the allocation granularity is higher than the page size of the system, so you should be able to safely use PAGE_SIZE as a substitute.